# WordPress Plugin enqueue scripts not working

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to load some scripts in the **front-end**. Been trying the code below (and variations of it) but doesn't do anything. Otherwise, the plugin is loading fine (using custom shortcode).

```
class MyPluginClass {   
    function load_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script('any_unique_id_is_ok', plugins_url('/somefolder/somefile.js', __FILE__),array('jquery'));
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array('MyPluginClass','load_scripts'));
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try: wp_enqueue_script('any_unique_id_is_ok', plugins_url('/somefolder/somefile.js', __FILE__),array('jquery'),null,false);

Comment: Sorry not working

Comment: Try taking "load_scripts" outside of class.

Comment: Yeah tried that as well. Didn't work sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who might stumble upon this issue, the problem was the missing `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` hooks in my custom theme. Put these into the relevant places and everything should work fine.